# No focus dotted-line shown for window with a control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a window whose UI comes from a control template, then the dotted line that shows keyboard focus (the "focus visual") doesn't show up. If I reimplement using direct content, rather than a control template, then the focus visual works fine.

Anyone know how to have the focus visual when using a control template?

I originally used XAML, but to rule it out, I did demo code in C#. I'm happy with a XAML-based solution, too.

[image]

**Class1.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

class Class1 : Window
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Title = "Class1";
        Height = 150;
        Width = 300;

        Template = new ControlTemplate() {
            VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Template1))
        };
    }

    class Template1 : StackPanel
    {
        public Template1()
        {
            Background = Brushes.White;
            Children.Add(new TextBox());
            Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 1" });
            Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "button 2" });
        }
    }
}
```

**Class2.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
class Class2 : Window
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Title = "Class2";
        Height = 150;
        Width = 300;

        Content = new StackPanel
        {
            Children =
            {
                new TextBox(),
                new Button() { Content = "button 1" },
                new Button() { Content = "button 2" },
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.cs**

I just launched the custom windows from MainWindow...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (new Class1()).Show();
        (new Class2()).Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this issue is caused because there is no adorner-layer in `Class1` window's visual tree, but is there in `Class2` window's visual tree.

[image: previous visual tree]

When an framework-element gets keyboard-focus, it seems it tries to assign the focus-visual style through an adorner-layer. (*Reference:* Source code for [`FrameworkElement`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,e02385c2dfd3c39c), and [`KeyboardNavigation`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Input/KeyboardNavigation.cs,0b7e549aa5f5926f))

**Option #1** Simplest solution would be change your code to include a `ContentControl` in your code (and re-template it):

```
public Class1()
{
    Title = "Class1";
    Height = 150;
    Width = 300;

    Content = new ContentControl
    {
        Template = new ControlTemplate()
        {
            VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Template1))
        }
    };
}
```

And the new visual-tree has the adorner-layer, and therefore the focus visual style:

[image: new visual tree] [image: visual style]

**Option #2** Or, another solution would be to ensure your template has an `AdornerDecorator` - [more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969824(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Template1 : Grid
{
    public Template1()
    {
        Background = Brushes.White;
        Children.Add(
            new AdornerDecorator()
            {
                Child = new StackPanel
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new TextBox(),
                        new Button() { Content = "button 1" },
                        new Button() { Content = "button 2" },
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

*Note:* I am not exactly sure why the adorner is added by default when you re-template a `ContentControl`, while it doesn't for the case of `Window`.
*Update 05/25:* Just realized that, the adorner we see while using custom template for `ContentControl` is from `Window`'s default template.

**Option #3** If you're doing it in XAML, just wrap your elements in `<AdornerDecorator>`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox/>
            <Button Content="Button 1"/>
            <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</ControlTemplate>
```